# Using RallyRestToolkitFor.NET how to assign a release to hierarchicalrequirement?

Tags: rally, agile-central

I am a newbie and need help with assigning a release to hierarchicalrequirement using Rally REST Toolkit for .NET.

I am able to update a lot of fields but having issues with chaning Release field.

I tried the following:

```
...
restApi = new RallyRestApi("xxx@yy.com", "password", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");
DynamicJsonObject toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();
toUpdate["Release._ref"] = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/release/23453434";
OperationResult updateResult = restApi.Update('hierarchicalrequirement', 1234323, toUpdate);

Also, tried 
toUpdate["Release.Name"] = "ABCDRelease";
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Regards
Kanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're super close.  All object associations work the same in the Web Services API.  Simply set its ref:

```
toUpdate["Release"] = "/release/23453434";
```

Note the ref can be absolute as in your original code or relative, as shown above.